# Vercel next.js environment variable not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, next.js, vercel

I'm using google maps in a Next.js project and everything's working locally. The google maps secret key is being stored in next.config.js which I access in the code through process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLEMAPS

When I deployed the project to Vercel, I didn't include next.js.config for security reasons. So I added the key under Settings -> Environment Variables
[image]

However, the environment variable is not working in production. When I console log process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLEMAPS, I get undefined

What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

This is how I got my setup to work...

1. I have an `env.local` file for local dev key. **Add `.env.local.*` to .gitignore** This file has my key/value pair like so:

> `1   NEXT_PUBLIC_G_KEY=AFLkefjlkwblahblahblah`

2. I have a next.config.js file that has this key as well in an `env` space:

> `env: {  NEXT_PUBLIC_G_KEY: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_G_KEY  }` (process.env works out of the box according to the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables))

3. I deploy to vercel so I create a secret with the actual value of the key...:

> `$> yarn now secret add MyAppName_PRoD_G_KEY AFLkefjlkwblahblahblah`

4. i go to my app in vercel > settings > environment variables and create a new one in the UI, mapped to the *secret* i just made in the command line.

[image: vercel environment variable mapped to secret]

Comment: `yarn now secret add` - you sure about this? I get `Command "now" not found.`

Comment: @Paul Truuuuee, this was applicable at the time of writing in 2021.
 
`now` has changed to `vercel`, and the command has changed as well; to: 
`vercel secrets add [secret-name] [secret-value]`
as documented here: https://vercel.com/docs/cli/secrets

Ideally the documentation stays current-ish; the idea you're going to google on is "adding nextjs secrets via CLI"

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked only by adding them through the vercel interface (I had some interference because of the `next.config.js` file, however as soon as I added that to .gitignore everything worked).

Answer (score 0):

If you have restricted the IP addresses that can access your Google Maps API, most probably Vercel IP is denied access by Google. Maybe your .env variable is working but the problem is Google Maps IP address restriction.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem. Turned out that Vercel exposes only variables that start with NEXT_PUBLIC. E.g. NEXT_PUBLIC_PRODUCTION_BE_API. Hope this helps.